# Defining Tables, Views, and Indexes in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

In AWS CloudFormation, you can define a stack of services with a JSON/YAML template. In particular, I am using [Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html) and [Aurora](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html) clusters.

The template allows you to define administrative properties of the cluster, but there doesn't seem to be a clear way to define tables, views, and indexes in the cluster such that when I push updates of stack, the DB's automatically update the schema as needed, similar to the way it manages updates to full stacks.

Is there a way to manage the schema of Redshift and Aurora databases in Cloud Formation?

Comment: I don't think CF supports application level configuration like what you described. You might need to write your own script and invoke them from CF is an option you could try. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#cfninit   I am not sure how much you could achieve with this.

Comment: @kosa This looks ideal, except that I can't see a way to make it work with Redshift/Aurora. Looks like it's only for EC2. Do you know how to make it work with databases?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, one approach I am thinking is, run a shell script, but I haven't done it in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Work in Progess!!** I'll update once I am sure that it is working!

So crawling documentation, Github and an hour on chat with AWS yields that I might need to create a [parent and child stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) ([example templates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudformation.html)). The parent stack would contain a [SNS Topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html), [SNS Subscription](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html) and [Lambda Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html) that monitor the child stack.

A parent stack might look like,

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  StackEventTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic

  StackEventEmailSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Protocol: email
      Endpoint: <your email>@gmail.com
      TopicArn:
        Ref: StackEventTopic

  StackEventLambdaSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Protocol: lambda
      Endpoint:
        Ref: StackEventHandler
      TopicArn:
        Ref: StackEventTopic

  StackEventHandler:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      ... configure your Lambda ...

  ChildStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      NotificationARNs:
        Ref: StackEventTopic
      TemplateURL: "s3 url for template YAML"
```

Answer (score 3):

Amazon CloudFormation can be used to create AWS resources. Think of it as **calling the standard AWS APIs on your behalf**.

Where the 'contents' of a resource can be controlled by an AWS API call, 
CloudFormation can also manage it. For example, creating a table in Amazon DynamoDB, a bucket in Amazon S3 and a stream in Amazon Kinesis. These are examples of services that are **region-wide and fully provided by AWS**.

In contrast, where a service must be deployed within an Availability Zone, CloudFormation has no access. Examples are: Amazon EC2 instances, Amazon RDS instances, Amazon Redshift clusters, Amazon EMR clusters and Amazon Elasticsearch clusters. They all **run on top of a virtual machine** and the 'contents' are not accessible by AWS API calls.

The only way to perform automatic actions in such systems is to **call them directly**. For example, establishing a JDBC connection to a database and then passing some SQL commands. This could be done from an application running on an Amazon EC2 instance, from an AWS Lambda function or from any computer connected to the Internet.

Amazon CloudFormation can trigger an [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html). This Lambda function could then perform practically any function, but you would be responsible for coding this function.

Comment: You could probably remove the first 3 paragraphs as they don't contribute to the answer. I already know how CF works. I would be more interested if Lambda can be triggered on creation to run only once and die. In that single call, It would need to be triggered with hostnames, usernames and passwords so it can connect to the DB and create schema. Eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350483/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-lambda-on-creation-from-cloudformation-template

Comment: You can trigger an AWS Lambda function as a Custom Resource. You could use `DependsOn` to wait for a particular resource to be instantiated prior to calling the function.

Comment: How do you hand it DB keys?

Comment: That is totally up to you and your code. You could consider assigning a Role to the Lambda function that has permissions to access the [Systems Manager Parameter Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html).

Comment: If you update your answer, I will accept it. All I need is how to write the SAM template to include a Lambda function that only triggers on create and has access to the DB (a Role works for me).