# Same CloudFormation template to parameterize DeletionPolicy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, policy

As a DevOps guy I wanted to use the same template to provision both Dev and Prod stacks... Where dev stacks should not have any `DeletionPolicy` but Prod stacks should utilize a `DeletionPolicy`

So, at first sight CFT gives an ok tooling for this but.... there is no possibility to parametrize S3 `DeletionPolicy` (that I've been able to locate at least)...

Here's some threads I dug up

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=560586
- https://www.unixdaemon.net/cloud/cloudformation-annoyance-deletion-policy-parameters/

The *suggested workaround* from AWS was to make the whole resource conditional, which leads us duplicating the resource and create a `„Deletable` and `„Undeletable` versions of it and all the depending resources should handle that condition...

This seems wonky and bloated, is there a way to parameterize this or a better methodology to accomplish my end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like there's an option in CFT other than resource duplication.

What you can do is create a Lambda with a Python script that would setup the S3 deletion policy. That Lambda function can be triggered through SNS during CloudFormation stack creation. Here is described how this can be configured:
[Is it possible to trigger a lambda on creation from CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350483/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-lambda-on-creation-from-cloudformation-template)

But in your particular case I'd go with resource duplication in same CFT.

Comment: Yeah thought it was pretty pipey dreamy ;) accepted as answer and +1

Comment: There are so many option in AWS to make things even more complicated lol Props to you for keeping on looking for a better solution.