# Run Crawler using custom resource Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I am trying to create and invoke an AWS Glue crawler using cloud formation. The creation part of the crawler(dynamo DB as target) is in lambda function.

how can I achieve all this using cloud formation? i.e creation of lambda function from cod present in s3 , After lambda function is created, it should get triggered to create crawler and then crawler should be invoked to create targted tables. I want all of this is cloud formation.

link for reference: [Is it possible to trigger a lambda on creation from CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350483/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-lambda-on-creation-from-cloudformation-template)

Answer (score 0):

You should write cloudformation to deploy crawler. And then in your ci/cd, write shell/python script to run crawler after it is deployed through cloudformation.