# Can I use an AWS Cloudformation template to create and modify tables in AWS Aurora (Postgres flavour)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I am looking for a way to manage schema changes to my AWS Aurora Postgres instance.

My whole AWS stack is set up using a Cloudformation template which is used to automatically deploy the stack when a change is detected in the source control. The Cloudformation template is built, a change set is prepared and finally excecuted on the stack.

I was hoping that the table definition of my Aurora instance could go inside the Cloudformation template somehow, so the schema migrations could be a part of the change set. Is this possible?

Note, I have seen this recommendation: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/rds-code-change-deployment/

Answer (score 1):

For anything custom like that use a Custom Resource Lambda that you can include in your Cloud Formation stack. The Lambda will need a layer for your postgress driver and it needs to include the migration script in the Lambda.

See the answer at this link, you will get 3 different options how you can trigger the Lambda.

[Is it possible to trigger a lambda on creation from CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350483/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-lambda-on-creation-from-cloudformation-template)