# Execute Lambda Function on CloudFormation Stack delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stack, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Is there a way to **trigger Lambda Function** declared in the very same CFN template that was used to create a stack when the given **stack** is being **deleted**?
Preferably I'd like to implement somewhat opposite to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445121/7060163) snippet (that is: a relatively simple solution that omits e.g. the need of creating SNS topics etc.).
<sup>In advance thx for any advices. Best regards! //M</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by creating a `CustomResource` and hooking it up with your lambda function.
From the [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html):

> With AWS Lambda functions and custom resources, you can run custom code in response to stack events (create, update, and delete)

The lambda function needs to react to a [Delete event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-requesttypes-delete.html), so it has to be written to allow for that.

---

**Example lambda function source code**

Here's an example for the AWS lambda function configuration, which needs to react to a delete event:

```
import cfnresponse
            
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = {}
        if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
            ... # do stuff
            response['output'] = ' Delete event.'
    cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, response)
```

**Example lambda function**

Here's a CloudFormation snippet for the lambda function:

```
"MyDeletionLambda": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Code": {
      "ZipFile": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "\n",
          [
            "import cfnresponse",
            "",
            "def lambda_handler(event, context):",
            "    response = {}",
            "    if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':",
            "        response['output'] = 'Delete event.'",
            "    cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, response)"
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
    "Runtime": "python3.8"
    }
  }
}
```

**Example custom resource**

Here's a CloudFormation snippet for a custom resource:

```
"OnStackDeletion": {
  "Type": "Custom::LambdaDependency",
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "MyDeletionLambda",
        "Arn"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```