# Can Cloudformation trigger event after creation of each resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating aws resources via cloudformation template.
I need to call a lambda after the creation of a DynamoDB table resource which will populate certain default records in it. After populating the default records only the rest of the resources should be created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to trigger a lambda on creation from CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350483/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-lambda-on-creation-from-cloudformation-template)

Comment: the triggered lambda should be run only once. Not more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should create a custom resource, see docs [custom resources in cfn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). Let this lambda create what ever records you need and then call back with a success signal once done. What ever resources you need to put on hold can have a "DependsOn" on your custom resource.

Comment: It should be run only once. Not more than that.

Comment: @Hakuna won't it be possible to configure the Lambda backed custom resource to run only on create, and just return directly for any update or delete events without inserting anything in the DynamoDB table?

Comment: Create your custom resource so it isnt triggered on stack updates, only create and perhaps delete if you need to clean things away.