# How to trigger an any aws resource based on creation of another aws resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation template to build a dynamo db ( see below), once the stack builds successfully, I would like to alert/notify/trigger another aws resource, like a lambda function or a step function or a aws data pipeline to start such that I can start populating the dynamo. what is the best way to trigger another process or aws resource once cloudformation stack creation is successful ?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: AWS CloudFormation Template To Create a DynamoDB

Parameters:
  HashKeyElementName:
    Type: String
    Default: Id
    Description: Hash Key Name
  HashKeyElementType:
    Type: String
    Default: S
    Description: Hash Key Type
Resources:
  Table:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: MyTable
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - 
          AttributeName: !Ref HashKeyElementName
          AttributeType: !Ref HashKeyElementType
      KeySchema:
        - 
          AttributeName: !Ref HashKeyElementName
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5 
Outputs:
  MyTable:
    Description: Table Created using this template.
    Value: !Ref Table
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70742972/can-cloudformation-trigger-event-after-creation-of-each-resource Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup SNS topic and a lambda function to get events from stack creation. An example of how to do it is given in AWS docs:

- [How can I receive an email alert when my AWS CloudFormation stack enters ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS status?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-rollback-email/)

You would have to adapt the example and the lambda to suit your needs.